# encrypt the data from SQL injections

Tags: php

Please tell me how to correctly encrypt the data (username, email, message) sent to the server from sql injections. I can not understand the syntax of the record itself.

My php handler

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['captcha']) && $_SESSION['captcha']===$_POST['captcha']){
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])){

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $db_host = "localhost"; 
        $db_user = "alekspvn"; // Логин БД
        $db_password = "123"; // Пароль БД
        $db_table = "book"; // Имя Таблицы БД

    $connect_db=mysql_connect(HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS)   
        or die("No connection with SQL"); 

        mysql_select_db("guests_db",$connect_db);

        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$connect_db);

        $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (username,email,message) VALUES ('$username','$email','$message')");
        echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Added to db']);
    } 
}
else { 
   echo json_encode(['error' => false, 'message' => 'Wrong captcha']);
}
```

Comment: convert password and username , emails details in md5

Comment: I believe "SQL Injection" is typically used to refer to an attack involving executing undesired SQL code on a server. What do you mean by "SQL Injection"?

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_*`, you should parameterize. `PDO` or `mysqli` allow for parameterized queries.

Comment: i don't understand how to write that

Answer (score 1):

**Convert You `Username` and `Password` into `password_hash` to store**

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: You should never use md5() on passwords. It is trivial to reverse. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash

Comment: MD5 is not suitable for hashing passwords, PHP has a password hashing lib that is much better

Comment: @JimL Okk Fine I going to update

Comment: There are no passwords being saved here. `username, email, message`.